# Printing out a certain number of prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print out a number of prime numbers that the user inputs, e.g if the user inputs 10 it will print out the first 10 prime numbers.

```
users_prime = int(input("How many primes do you want to find"))

primes = [2]

counter = 2

while len(primes) < users_prime:

    for x in primes:
        if x % counter:
            primes.append(counter)
            counter += 1

        if x % counter == 0:
            counter += 1

print("The prime numbers are:", primes)
```

Here are my instructions.
[image: Here are my instructions]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `counter % x` instead of `x % counter`?

Comment: Also you should append to `primes` only if `counter` is no divisible be all values of `x`

Comment: You add `counter` multiple times in `primes`, and look in your `for` at values in `primes`, i guess it gives a new version of infinite loop

Comment: Yes when I run my code nothing happens as you said "infinite loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users_prime = int(input("How many primes do you want to find"))

primes = [2]
counter = primes[0]+1

while len(primes) < users_prime:
    for x in primes:
        if counter % x:
            continue
        else:
            break

    if x == primes[-1]:
        primes.append(counter)
    counter += 2

print("The prime numbers are:", primes)
```

Steps: Initialize counter to first prime plus one. Check if the number you are checking is not divisable by a previous prime number. If not, add this number to the list of prime number. Add +2 to counter to avoid even number.

**Edit**: This solution is not the fastest one. We can work on speed improvement if needed.

Output: `('The prime numbers are:', [2, 3, 5, 7, 11])`

**Edit 2:**
First point, initialization of `counter`, you know that 2 is a prime number, so no need to check it. It is already in the prime numbers list. So you can initialize it to the next integer. (Here 3 or `prime[0]+1`)
Then, your first `if`: it has to be `counter % x` as you want to check if `counter` is a prime number or not. Else (your version), you check if your prime number is divisible by `counter` i.e. the number you assume is prime (unless the algo is telling you otherwise).
In my version, i check if `counter` is divisible by any previous prime number. If it is not divisible, i continue. If `counter` is a multiple of any prime number, it goes in the `else` so my `for` loop is broken. As a consequence, if `counter` is a multiple of any of the prime number `x` will not be equal to the last element of prime. If so, i'm not doing anything. Else i add `x` to the list of prime number.
As for the `counter += 2`, it will avoid 4, 6, 8, 10, ..., 2*i which correspond to even numbers (that can not be prime numbers)

**Edit 3:**
To be correct, you should actually use boolean (i apologize i didn't realize before). Else if `counter` is a multiple of `prime[-1]` it is still added to the prime list.

```
isprime = True
for x in primes:
    if counter % x:
        continue
    else:
        isprime = False
        break

if isprime:
    primes.append(counter)
counter += 2
```

Comment: This does work but Im only a beginner so I'm not sure about some of the stuff you have done. Can you make it closer to my original code?

Comment: Quite tired now, but this is making sense. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Could you please run me trough how 5 ends up on the prime number list. In regards to this section.                                                                          
 If x == primes[-1]:
    primes.append(counter)
 counter += 2

Comment: Primes start with 2. Counter to 3, as 3 is not a multiple of 2, 3 is added to the prime list. Then we add 2 to counter, counter is now 5. We check if 5 is multiple of 2 (x=2), which is not so we continue in the prime list: we check if 5 is a multiple of 3 (x=3), which is not so for loop continue and finish. x(=3) is equal to primes[-1] (=3) so we add 5 to prime list.

Comment: @Droid2: I made another edit, there was a case not taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

it may help to break your code into parts (functions). you could take out the part that checks whether or not a candidate is a prime (note that you only need to do trial division up to `sqrt(candidate)`; and you only need to check odd numbers):

```
# from itertools import count
from math import ceil, sqrt

users_prime = int(input("How many primes do you want to find? "))
primes = [2]

def check_prime(candidate):
    mx = ceil(sqrt(candidate))  # need only check up to mx
    for prime in primes:
        if candidate % prime == 0:
            return False
        if prime >= mx:
            return True

# for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
candidate = 1
while True:
    candidate += 2  # checking 3, 5, 7, 9, ... only
    if check_prime(candidate):
        primes.append(candidate)
    if len(primes) >= users_prime:
        break

print("The prime numbers are:", primes)
```

the commented part (using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) would just be a nicer way to iterate over `3, 5, 7, ...` than the `while True` loop.

the difference you then see between this code and yours (apart from the fact that your test `x % counter` is the wrong way round) is that you check for primes and accept if the test fails in the same loop (without having tested *all* the primes first); my example has 2 loops: one for primalty testing and one to loop over the candidates.